# Why is this div with 100vh height not covering the whole viewport?

Tags: html, css

The blue div in this code has a height of 100vh whereas the red div has the height of 5000px. Shouldn't the blue div extend itself to cover the whole viewport because of the 100vh height attribute?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: absolute; left: 35%; width: 100px; height: 100vh; background-color: blue;">
</div>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 50%; width: 100px; height: 5000px; background-color: red;"></div>
```

What I want to achieve from this is that suppose there's some text which overflows on sizing down the window then how should I get around that situation so that the 100vh height div again covers up the new window size?

Comment: It works as expected from your CSS. viewport is height  seen of the window, what overflows is not part of it

Comment: you are having an overflow, and overflow doesn't count in viewport height

Comment: Suppose there's some text which overflows on sizing down the window. How should I get around that situation so that the 100vh height div again covers up the new window size?

Comment: can you share a real use case? because in this situation I would simply set the same height for both

Comment: Sounds like you have an overflow issue not a height issue.  Check out https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp.  If you want the div to scroll with the text then set `overflow: auto` if you want the text to be hidden the set `overflow: hidden`

Comment: It's a real use case. I have made a page for practice and when I reduce the width of the browser window then the text wraps up and overflows. The div shaped like a column on the left side of page which is supposed to cover the whole page height doesn't keep up with it and stays short.

Comment: Can you please explain me what's messing up the left column height in this page (see leftcol class) https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtBhfP2XvzeziFrQvzTiFmIWu_L6 @SteveK

Comment: if this your real case, so better provide it within the question is we can better help you

Comment: @NeerajKumar What do you mean what is messing up the `.leftcol` it is exacly 100% of the viewport height?  If you mean why does it stretch past the bottom of the page it is because your header takes up a part of the viewports height so your column is past the bottom of the page exactly the height of the header.  If you remove the header then you would see that your column is 100% of the viewports height.

Comment: @SteveK I understand that. I was asking, that it is not covering the bottom part of the page the way my header with 100vw width covers the whole width even on resizing or horizontal overflows. Is there anyway to get similar behaviour?

Comment: @NeerajKumar I see what you are getting at now.  You need to have a wrapper around your sidebar and your main content and then you can set your sidebar to have a height of 100% and it will follow your main content down the page.  I am in the middle of something right now but I will try and set up a quick fiddle here in a little bit.  I think you are thinking about how to set this up wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Viewport height just means that the height of the element will be a percentage of the viewport.  The viewport being the window your viewing the page on.  So if it is a 1920x1080 screen the viewport height will be 1080px or whatever your browser window is, it may be less if you have a toolbar at the bottom of your screen.  The issue you are having is that if you want the sidebar to follow the main content down the page you need to disregard the viewport and have a wrapper around both of them like so:

```css
.main-wrapper{
  display:flex;
}

aside{
   background:blue;
   color:#fff;
   width:200px;
}

main{
  background:green;
  height:5000px;
  flex:1
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <aside>Your sidebar</aside>
  <main>Your Main Content</main>
</div>
```

That being said you may want to check out the following fiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/g49qzn3v/).  I have made this fiddle responsive for mobile screens so you may have to resize the output window larger to view the sidebar layout.  The issue is you are absolutely positioning items and fixing items outside divs which is bad practice.  In your example you commented on above you have many layout and z-index issues that you will run into.  This fiddle is just an example but it should give you a good frame of reference on how the layout should be thought of.

Comment: The answer that actually helps out; thank you!

Answer (score -2):

It is happening because that's how vh works.
vh is based on the height of viewport. 1vh =  1% of viewport height.

https://www.sitepoint.com/css-viewport-units-quick-start/

Comment: Suppose there's some text which overflows on sizing down the window. How should I get around that situation so that the 100vh height div again covers up the new window size?

Comment: If the text is more than containers new height than you can use overflow:auto; it will create a scrollable container and text will not flow out.

Answer (score -2):

`1vh` is Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport*

so **`100vh`** will correspond to **100% of the height of the viewport**

[demo here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_unit_vh)

For further details please refer to the [CSS Units documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp).